# what is the best way or pattern to create a Wrapper class to abstract the use of RabbitMQ in node js

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

so I'm using RabbitMQ for some Projects and i noticed that i ll use some duplicate code all the Time that's why i decided to make a Wrapper Class or Interface that have some function to use RabbitMQ direct without repeating the code all the time. i began to do this yesterday and i already had some Problems since i wanted to use OOP and Javascript can be complicated when using OOP (at least i think so)

I began with creating a class IRAbbitMQ with function init to initialize a connection and create a channel, i knew that i cant use nested classes so instead i wanted to use Factory functions, i tried to make the connection and channel a part of the class IRabbitMQ properties but i dont know why that gave me undefined when i create an instance of it

```
class IRabbitMQ {

constructor() {

    this.init(rabbitMQServer); // rabbitMQServer for example 'localhost//5672'

}
// establish a Connection to RAbbitMQ Server
async init(host) {

    try {

    let connection = await amqplib.connect(host);

    let channel = await connection.createChannel();

    channel.prefetch(1); 

    console.log(' [x] Awaiting RPC requests');

    this.connection = connection;

    this.channel = channel;

    }

    catch(err) {

        console.error(err);
    }

}

// Close the Connection with RabbitMQ
closeConnection() {

    this.connection.close();
}

log() {
    console.log(this.connection);
}

EventPublisher() {

    function init(IRabbit, publisherName) {

        if(!IRabbit.connection) {

            throw new Error('Create an Instance of IRabbitMQ to establish a Connection');

        }

        let ch = IRabbit.channel;
        console.log(ch);
    }
    return {
        init : init
    }   
    }

   }

   var r = new IRabbitMQ();
   r.log();
```

when i run the code the output is undefined, i dont know why since i m initializing the connection and channel properties in the init function and then called that function in the constructor so that should be initialized when i create an object of the Wrapper class. i wanted also to take some advices from you wether it is good to use classes or is there any other better way to create a Wrapper class or Interface for RabbitMQ to make it easy to use it and not have to duplicate Code.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "the output is undefined", meaning it logs "undefined" somewhere? It's just not clear to me where/what is failing 

Comment: there is a function called log() which will console.log(this.connection), with that function i tested if the connection to rabbitmq happened or not. When i call that function it console.log undefined instead of the connection that means that the class Property connection have the value undefined instead of the real connection and that confuses me because when i console.log the connection property from inside the init function than it works and logs the real connection object. hope that ll help you understand the question

Comment: Well you prob have a racing condition in that case? The constructor calls `init()` which is async. So when you create an instance of the object and then call directly `.log()` the chance is that the `init()` did not complete yet as it's async at that point. A factory function would be better then, for example `const myRabbit = await RabbitMQFactory.create()`. Not especially that `await` in front of the factory function.

Comment: it didnt work with a Factory function too :( maybe you can show me some code if it works with you, that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I was able to successfully log the `connection` with this example code. I trimmed out other code to just focus on the `.log()` part that was logging a `undefined`.

Code is far from perfect, but works at least

```
const amqplib = require('amqplib');

class IRabbitMQ {

    constructor() { }

    async init(host) {
        try {
            const connection = await amqplib.connect(host);
            const channel = await connection.createChannel();
            channel.prefetch(1);
            console.log(' [x] Awaiting RPC requests');
            this.connection = connection;
            this.channel = channel;
        }catch(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }

    log() {
        console.log(this.connection);
    }
}

async function createInstance(){
    const instance = new IRabbitMQ();
    try {
        await instance.init('amqp://localhost');
    }catch (e) {
        throw new Error('OOPS!');
    }
    return instance;
}

async function runLogic() {
    const r = await createInstance();
    r.log();
}

runLogic().catch(console.log);
```

Just comment if you'd want me to give additional advice/tips, but this seems to work for me.

Comment: I thank you a lot for the Effort, although this may seem to work fine but as you said it is a little bit of a mess if my class will be structered like that and as i wrote in the description, my goal is actually to make a class Wrapper to wrap some functions so that i ll not need to repeat myself all the time and write kind of spaguetti Code. it works the way you do but my goal was not to log the connection property, i wanted that the connection to rabbitmq will be available as a property so i can use it for other classes or functions.

Comment: maybe this comment will help more, the goal is to wrap all the publish and subscribe functions in a class so that in a publisher file i ll only require this class and then make an instance and call the functions that are responsible for publishing the message and if i need to subscribe then i ll go to the subscribe file and make an instance of this class and then call the functions responsible for subscribing. this way will orginize my Work and if i had a Team then it ll be betterto maintain the Code. i hope this ll help and i thank you a lot and everyone who is trying to help :)

Comment: I personally would not try to force using a class. What you want is something "singleton"-ish in case you want to reuse the same connection (Right?). If that assumption is correct, I would just return from your node module an object with methods that you need and keep your state (like the connection) as a clojure in your file.

Comment: in this Situation the Problem would be that i cannot assign the connection to a Property of the Class or return it from function. for example in the function init when i assign this.connection = connection and when i want to call that connection property in another function or from an instance of the class than that connection will be undefined and i dont know why. if i forgot the class and use just a function that connect to rabbitmq and then return connection and then use it in my code for exp let c = establishConnection(); // here i get also undefined, I dont know why